# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRouteFromReactElement' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting this error :-
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRouteFromReactElement' of undefined
in this code. I used Router for navigation but not working. I imported a file called Home.jsx

```jsx
    var React = require('react')
    var ReactDOM =  require('react-dom')
    var Router = require('react-router').Router
    var Route= Router.Route
    var IndexRoute = Router.IndexRoute 

    var App = React.createClass({
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>App</p>
            <ul>
              <li>About</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })

var About = require('./components/Home')

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute path="/about" component={About} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

and Home.jsx

```jsx
var React = require('react');
var RaisedButton = require('material-ui/lib/raised-button');

var Home = React.createClass({
  render:function() {
    return (
        <RaisedButton label="Default" />
    );
  },
});

module.exports = Home;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things which you are doing wrong here. I'm assuming you are using React Router 1.0 (because of use of `IndexRoute`).

In version 1.0 `Router` component is a property of the top-level module, so this is how you would do your imports:

```js
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
```

I think you also not fully understand what `IndexRoute` is, have a look [in the docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/IndexRoutes.md#index-routes) for the clarification. But the tldr; is that the `IndexRoute` does not take the path argument.

Another thing is that to mount your routes components somewhere you need to specify where, and you can do it with use of `{this.props.children}`. So your could could look like:

```jsx
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>App</p>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var About = require('./components/Home')

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={About} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

Please have a look at the [Introduction docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md) so you will better understand how to use react router in your app.