# Element type is invalid (got: undefined) for react-redux component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-toolbox

I'm trying to create a component for `redux-form`. Here is my component

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Input from 'react-toolbox'

export const TextField = ({ input, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) => (
  <Input
    error={touched && error}
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />
)

TextField.propTypes = {
  input: PropTypes.object,
  meta: PropTypes.object
}

export default TextField
```

I also create an `index.js` file to easily import it

```
import TextField from './TextField'   
export default TextField
```

Then I use it like this

```
import TextField from 'components/TextField'
import { Field } from 'redux-form'
<form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit(props.loginUser)}>
  <Field type='email' label='Email' name='email' component={TextField} required />
</form>
```

But I get this error

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `TextField`.

I check again an again

- [the redux form doc](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/Field.md/)
- other related topic on SO like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135827/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-createroutefromreactelement-of-undefi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change:

```
import Input from 'react-toolbox'
```

to:

```
import Input from 'react-toolbox/lib/input';
```

or

```
import {Input} from 'react-toolbox';
```

Both should work

I think that in your case `Input` is undefined imported like that

Comment: Tanks a lot. Shame on me for missing it.